# Extract Number from String Python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract a certain numbers in a string, after numerous tries with regex, I can't seem to find the correct pattern for it. There are other numbers but I require only the 3 digits after "M". Thank you.

Example:
line: `"2018-01-23 - member data. member_id=[M001]."`

Result:

```
001
```

Comment: Please show us just one of your "numerous tries"!

Comment: why does not your output includes 2018 or 01 or 23, those are numbers as well. Somewhat ambiguous case to deal with

Comment: @Constance thanks to people like you Stackoverflow becomes an unwelcoming place. You can pass the same message in a more polite and welcoming way.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I only need the number after "M"

Comment: @Constance I have tried m = re.search(r'member_id=[M(\d+)]', line)

Comment: you can specify the numbers in \d+ like \d{3}. see my answer.

Comment: @alfasin - There is nothing wrong with Constance's comment. The op has had to click a button stating they read the page on asking a question as well as the question template for new users which they might have seen so there is no excuse for lack of effort.

Comment: @alfasin honestly that wasn't meant to be unwelcoming at all.  I said please, and I honestly tried to help the asker to improve the question.  No offence intended to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) as follows:

```
matches = re.findall( r'\[M(\d{3})\]', '2018-01-23 - member data. member_id=[M001].')
print(matches[0])

out:
001
```

**Explanation:**

```
\d will find any number.
{3} will find occurrence of the match.
```

Comment: You can put the explanation about that 3 in your answer. It will be useful for OP to use this code in other cases

Comment: @Rayhwx: re.findall will return list containing all matches. Your first match will be at zero index. visit re.findall docs that I attached.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you!
May I know when there is more than 1 "M" in a file, how do I include "member_id=" into regex pattern in order to find those 3 digits accurately?

Comment: even If I answer your this question, you may get another. Please read this. It wont take much. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with a capturing group as follows:

```
matches = re.findall( r'.*\[M(.*?)\]', '2018-01-23 - member data. member_id=[M001].')
print(matches[0]) # 001
```

Comment: Because re.findall will return list. if your need item you will have to get by it's index.

Answer (score 0):

You say you already tried this:

```
m = re.search(r'member_id=[M(\d+)]', line)
```

but you need to escape the `[` and `]` characters, as they have a special meaning here.  Try this:

```
m = re.search(r'member_id=\[M(\d+)\]', line)
```

Comment: It works! May I know how do I get all the values in the file? I have tried below method and it will become list in list. I have tried re.search, however it does not only stores the 3 digit in the list to print out.

for line in file:
    try:
        m = re.findall(r'member_id=\[M(\d+)\]', line)
        memberList.append(m) 
    except:
        m = None


print (*memberList,sep="\n")

Comment: memberList.append(m.group(1))